# Good practice to implement viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

Does anyone know good practice to implement viewmodel logic? Event based or action based?

```
class EventBasedVM : ViewModel() {
    fun onResume() {
        fetchInformation1()
        fetchInformation2()
    }
}

class ActionBasedVM : ViewModel() {
    fun fetchInformation1() {
    }

    fun fetchInformation2() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although both approaches you mentioned make sense for specific use cases, I would add another one to the list:

```
 class InitialisationBasedVM : ViewModel() {

    val informationLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    init {
        fetchInformation()
    }

    private fun fetchInformation() {
        // call you async code and eventually post the value to the observers
        informationLiveData.postValue("whatever")
    }
}
```

The approach of fetching data in the `ViewModel` constructor make sure data are not fetched again in case of configuration changes. You could also make the `fetchInformation()` method public and invoke from the View upon certain actions  that require reloading the data (i.e pull to refresh).

Comment: Fetch method is example. I could be use a POST method. It does not matter.

Comment: What I'm saying is that there is not a one-size-fits-all. Based on the specific use case you might want to implement it in different ways.